# Apply different validation rule in edit case Yii2

Tags: validation, yii2

In Yii2 we use `public function rules() { }` for validation, in view we use `$model->isNewRecord` for check mode, I want to check mode in rule function. I tried by `$this->isNewRecord` but it is not working.

Comment: show your model code..

Comment: use [scenario](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-model.html#scenarios%28%29-detail)

Comment: also check [this](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/guide-structure-models.html#scenarios) about using scenarios as suggested by @InsaneSkull

Comment: try to read docs of yii2 you will get every thing.Or try on http://bsourcecode.com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You implement different validation rules using scenarios.

In the controller you can set the different scenario on different actions or on different conditions in same action .

```
public function actionRegister(){
    $model = new User;
    $model->scenario = 'register';
}
```

You can then apply different validation rules to specific scenarios in your model

```
class User extends ActiveRecord {

public function rules()
{
    return [
        // email required in "register" scenario
        [['email'], 'required', 'on' => 'register'],

        // email, password are required in "login" scenario
        [['email', 'password'], 'required', 'on' => 'login'],
    ];
}

}
```

Comment: I didn't edit that, I edited an edit to correct some bad grammar ("actions" and "conditions" were singular) that I noticed while I was approving edits. I have no idea who changed the action name.

Comment: @MikeWise, no stress, I'll delete my comment above. Thanks for the feedback.